# Diode clipping Vbias replacement

Tags: diodes

I'm trying to get a grip on this circuit, I'd like to clip a signal with this circuit. I want it to clip anything above 5v. Taking into account 0.7v voltage drop of the diode, than Vbias would be 4.3v right? But how do I (without a battery..) get this 4.3 volts. I tried a voltage divider at the cathode of the diode, no good results.

My question is probably an easy one; how does one replace Vbias with REAL components? Iow: how can I build this circuit on my breadboard? (in this drawing it's drawn as a battery but I'm not using batteries in my circuit....not even considering..) (i'm guessing it's reaaaaaal simple, but I do not seem to get it...)

Please help understand this puzzle...

[image: Diode Clipping]

Answer (score 2):

Consider the use of a zener diode instead. It is placed in the opposite orientation without a bias voltage source, to clamp the output voltage to some limit. In order to prevent a secondary clipping to ground, a second non-Zener diode is used as well:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFTyDz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This behavior arises as a consequence of the zener diode's VI characteristic (reproduced from [here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_7.html)):

[image]

Notice the green zener region in the bottom left. There are three regions to consider:

- **Input voltage < 0**: D2 is reverse biased, so the output is unchanged.
- **Input voltage between 0 and Vz + 0.7 V**: There is not enough voltage to forward bias D2 and allow D1 to conduct.
- **Input voltage above Vz + 0.7 V**: The input voltage is large enough that D1 and D2 can conduct a large amount of current. Because that current must flow through the resistor, the output voltage is clamped to Vz + 0.7 V.

In order to make the clamping voltage 5 V, you'll need a 4.3 V zener.

Comment: Great tip! I do understand what you are saying, but then again I still do not know how to practically perform the original circuit... Could you shed some light on that as well?

Comment: Literally using this exact circuit.

Comment: @user3810130 you just use the circuit I drew at the top of my answer. I literally designed it for you and explained how it works.